# How resolve a problem of "However we cannot choose between the following variants of org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.8.10"

Tags: android, react-native

I have an old reactnative project that i am trying to run.
When i have installed the node modules and now running the app on an emulator i get this error below

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.      
   > A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-async-storage_async-storage'.  
      > Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':react-native-async-storage_async-storage:classpath'.
         > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.8.10.
           Required by:
               project :react-native-async-storage_async-storage
            > The consumer was configured to find a runtime of a component compatible with Java 11, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally. However we cannot choose between the following variants of org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.8.10: 
                - gradle70JavadocElements
                - gradle70RuntimeElements
                - gradle70SourcesElements
                - gradle71JavadocElements
                - gradle71RuntimeElements
                - gradle71SourcesElements
                - gradle75JavadocElements
                - gradle75RuntimeElements
                - gradle75SourcesElements
                - gradle76JavadocElements
                - gradle76RuntimeElements
                - gradle76SourcesElements
                - javadocElements
                - runtimeElementsWithFixedAttribute
                - sourcesElements
```

I have tried changing the java version, placing the "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.8.10" in the project but it was not initially there.

So i already have kotlin in my machine but i am not sure where the problem is because the library ":react-native-async-storage_async-storage" is the one causing the issue.

And i checked the project and there was no kotlin used before in the project, why is it asking for the kotlin now

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? running into the same issue.

Comment: @Marline not yet, and it is now turning into an annoying issue

Answer (score 3):

You can add `kotlinVersion` in `android/build.gradle` file within buildscript as follows

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        kotlinVersion = "1.6.21"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, this temporary workaround does the job:

downgrade react-native-async-storage

```
yarn upgrade @react-native-async-storage/async-storage@^1.10.0
```

And downgrade the Kotlin version in react-native-async-storage/build.gradle by replacing:

```
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$asyncStorageKtVersion"
```

with:

```
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.21"
```

Note that you might repeat the last step every time you change something in your node_modules